# How to rename id field in an entity using with elasticsearch?

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, spring-boot

Hi friends i am using elastic search with spring boot project and my primary database is mysql. My project is running fine with default configuration . Suppose my entity is CancelReason.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cancel_reason")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "cancelreason")
public class CancelReason implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)        
    @Column(name = "reason_code", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String reasonCode;
    .......
}
```

Now with this configuration my project is running and elastic search is working fine but my requirment is to make `reasonCode` primary key instead of `id` so i want to remove

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

this code. as i remove id field and make reasonCode primarykey and when i run my project it gives me this error:

```
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cancelReasonManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.megacabs.repository.search.CancelReasonSearchRepository in.megacabs.manager.CancelReasonManager.cancelReasonSearchRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cancelReasonSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class in.megacabs.domain.CancelReason!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at in.megacabs.Application.main(Application.java:77) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.megacabs.repository.search.CancelReasonSearchRepository in.megacabs.manager.CancelReasonManager.cancelReasonSearchRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cancelReasonSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class in.megacabs.domain.CancelReason!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Though mysql is working fine entity is beign created in mysql database but not in elasticsearch.
Please help!

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: i have edited stacktrace and i am using jhipster to make this project

Comment: Well, the Stacktrace says it cannot create cancelReasonSearchRepository. I don't think this is an elasticsearch issue. Have you changed the repository after you changed the CancelReason class? Maybe posting the repository (without methods) and the new CancelReason implementation can help us finding the problem.

Comment: I suppose you have added the `@Id` annotation to the reasonCode field?

Comment: yes i have added @Id

Comment: Hi @Qasim, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this annotations in the primary key field:

```
@Id
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
```

Regards.